# horizontal navigationbar not working with width specified

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to create a horizontal navigationbar with css.

The strange thing is, that if I set a width for my `ol` tag, the horizontal float doesn't work. If I remove the `width`, it works as expected.

What does cause this issue?

CSS:

```
nav {
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 240px;
    background-color: #8F8E93;
    float: left;
}

nav ol {
    width: 300px;
}


nav ol li {
    float: left;
}

nav>ol>li>a {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="reiseziele.html">Reiseziele</a></li>
    <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
      <ol>
        <li><a href="kontakt_mail.html">E-Mail</a></li>
        <li><a href="kontakt_formular.html">Formular</a></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Comment: You want 2 menu in nav bar and then sub menu..try to give width to inner li.

Comment: like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/07701dt7/1/)

Comment: Sure..give me min.

Comment: Semantically you should be using _ul_ instead of _ol_. But that's a small thing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give **width** to li but be careful while giving with css selectors or else it will affect the inner li too.

and use this css for inner li to avoid float left so they can be act like sub menu.

```
nav ol li ol li{
  float:none !important;;
}
```

and for outer ol li

```
nav ol li {
    float: left;
    width:50%;
}
```

I have override the float:none to inner child so they can come in drop downlist.

See [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/07701dt7/1/)

**Note** Always use clear:both after using float or else it will create white gap issue if width is not good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the flexbox-approach. It simplifies the whole thing a lot.

Additionally, I realized your nested sub-navigation with the `details` and `summary` tags.

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <a href="reiseziele.html">Reiseziele</a>

  <details id="container">
    <summary><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></summary>
    <a href="kontakt_mail.html">E-Mail</a>
    <a href="kontakt_formular.html">Formular</a>
  </details>

</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #8F8E93;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

nav ol {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/to7be/pen/XNjRLG